# ERROR FK LARAVEL CON TIMESTAMPS

Tags: laravel, eloquent, timestamp

Estoy creando el típico CRUD donde hay dos tablas relacionadas: `coches` y `elemento_banners`. En la función `Store` del modelo `ElementoBanner` recojo los datos del formulario por `POST`, los guardo y luego accedo al registro de la tabla `coches` para editar la columna `elemento_banner_id` y asignarle el nuevo `banner` creado. Os dejo el código:

FUNCIÓN STORE

```
         public function store(Request $request)
            {
    
    <---------------RECOJO LOS DATOS Y LOS GUARDO EN UNA VARIABLE PARA SUBIRLO A LA BBDD ------------------------>
                $banner = new ElementoBanner();
        
                $banner->coche_id = $request->coche_id;
                $banner->etiqueta = $request->etiqueta;
                $banner->mensaje_banner = $request->mensaje_banner;
        
                $banner->save();
    
    
    <-------------- ASIGNO LA RELACIÓN EN LA TABLA COCHES ------------------------->
                $coche = Coche::find($request->coche_id);
                $coche->elemento_banner_id = ElementoBanner::latest('id')->first();
        
                $coche->save();

<---------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^AQUI OCURRE EL ERROR----------------------------->
        
                return redirect("/admin/banner");
            }
```

Dejo el código del formulario por aquí:

```
<form action="/admin/banner" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="coche">Coche</label>
            <select type="text" class="form-control" id="etiqueta" name="coche_id" placeholder="Nombre identificativo para el banner">

                @foreach ($coches as $coche)
                    <option value="{{$coche->id}}">{{$coche->marca}} - {{$coche->nombre}} - {{$coche->precio}}€</option>

                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="etiqueta">Etiqueta</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="etiqueta" name="etiqueta" placeholder="Nombre identificativo para el banner">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mensaje_banner">Mensaje del banner</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mensaje_banner" name="mensaje_banner" placeholder="Mensaje que se mostrará en el banner">
        </div>

        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-opcion hvr-sweep-to-top">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

El error que me devuelve tiene que ver con los campos TIMESTAMPS, por alguna extraña razón que desconozco está utilizando un formato de hora súper extraño.

Os dejo el mensaje de error aquí:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer
> value: '{"id":7,"coche_id":9,"mensaje_banner":"Audi Serie 1 1.2 para
> vasil\u00e1h","created_at":"2021-03-27T12:20:49.000000Z","update...'
> for column `coches_y_gestor`.`coches`.`elemento_banner_id` at row 1
> (SQL: update `coches` set `elemento_banner_id` =
> {"id":7,"coche_id":9,"mensaje_banner":"Audi Serie 1 1.2 para
> vasil\u00e1h","created_at":"2021-03-27T12:20:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-27T12:20:49.000000Z","etiqueta":"Banner
> editado"}, `coches`.`updated_at` = 2021-03-27 12:20:49 where `id` = 9)

Comment: `elemento_banner_id ` es de tipo JSON? Poirque le estas pasando todo el resultado de `ElementoBanner::latest('id')->first()`

Comment: Correcto, no había caido en eso. Vvoy a corregirlo y te comento muchisimas gracias Juan

Comment: Efectivamente ahí estaba el error Juan!! siempre está en tus narices y no lo ves jajajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta aquí en estas lineas

```
 $coche = Coche::find($request->coche_id);
 $coche->elemento_banner_id = ElementoBanner::latest('id')->first();
```

Es un objeto completo y no un valor, debería ser así.

```
$coche->elemento_banner_id = ElementoBanner::latest('id')->first()->id;
```

Te recomiendo no volver a hacer la llamada a la base de datos para obtener este valor, ya que al haber `$banner->save();` este ya recupera el id, por lo que un código más optimo sería

```
$coche = Coche::find($request->coche_id);
$coche->elemento_banner_id = $banner->id;
```

También puedes usar `$foo->refresh();` en determidas situaciones para refrescar un modelo, y obtener por ejemplo una relación de este que se ha modificado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente el error estaba ahí!! Me apunto el consejo de no volver a llamar a la BBDD ;) y el ‘refresh’ Saludos